# Filtering static/stationary areas

Tags: python, pandas, sensors

I was trying to filter my sensor data. My objective is to filter the sensor data where the data is more or less stationary over a period of time. can anyone help me in this

```
time : 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20  

sensor : 121
115
122
123
116
117
113
116
113
114
115
112
116
129
123
125
130
120
121
122
```

this is a sample data, i need to take the first data and compare it to the next 20 seconds of data, if all the 20 datas is in the the range of +or- 10 then i need to filter these 20 datas to another column, and i need to continue this process of filtering

Comment: Mention reproducible sample dataset and also the expected output DataFrame which you want in the question. Also put in your efforts which you have tried

Comment: I dont know how can I mention the sample dataset, since Im so new in this forum. what I need is to filter the data, where the data is more in between some values over a period of time. like to filter the steady state

Comment: Whichever sensor data you are asking the question about you can put few rows of that dataset by editing your question and expected output you can show by explaining from that sample what you want to have out that data, this will help the community understand what your actual problem is

Comment: I tried my level best, I have edited and im not able to add any images.

Comment: is the data which i have given is understandable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However your question is not very clear but from my understanding what you want is between time duration of 20 seconds if the sensor is in between the range of +10 and -10 from the first reading then you have to append those values to new column and above or below that should not be considered. I tried replicating your DataFrame and you could go ahead in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'time':[1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23], 
        'sensor':[121, 115, 122, 123,116,117,113,116,113,114,115,112,116,129,123,125,130,120,121,122,123,124,144]}

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data) #I am taking time duration of 23 seconds where 23rd second data is out of range as 144 - 121 > 10

    time  sensor
0      1     121
1      2     115
2      3     122
3      4     123
4      5     116
5      6     117
6      7     113
7      8     116
8      9     113
9     10     114
10    11     115
11    12     112
12    13     116
13    14     129
14    15     123
15    16     125
16    17     130
17    18     120
18    19     121
19    20     122
20    21     123
21    22     124
22    23     144

list = []
for i in range(0, len(df_new['sensor'])):
    if 0 <= df_new['time'][i] - df_new['time'][0] <= 23: #you take here 20 which is your requirement instead of 23 as I am doing to demonstrate for the value of 144
        if -10 < df_new['sensor'][0] - df_new['sensor'][i] < 10:
            list.append(df_new['sensor'][i])
        else:
            list.append('out of range')
    else:
        break

df_new['result'] = list

df_new

    time  sensor          result
0      1     121           121
1      2     115           115
2      3     122           122
3      4     123           123
4      5     116           116
5      6     117           117
6      7     113           113
7      8     116           116
8      9     113           113
9     10     114           114
10    11     115           115
11    12     112           112
12    13     116           116
13    14     129           129
14    15     123           123
15    16     125           125
16    17     130           130
17    18     120           120
18    19     121           121
19    20     122           122
20    21     123           123
21    22     124           124
22    23     144  out of range
```

Comment: thank you so much, i know my question is not much clear. this is something i was looking since im new in programming field. Can i ask one more, what if the case is like, i need to start from the 10th second and look for +10 sec and -10 sec if the difference it in between +10 and -10?

Comment: i just copied your code, but im not getting the out, im getting the last two rows only, that is 124 and out of range... idk why?

Comment: The code i have written on the logic what you explained in the question and the dataframe which i created. Have you defined the empty list i missed that in my answer i have added it now so updated my answer with ‘list = []’

Comment: To your second question yes that can be done just tweak the logic in the both the ‘if’ conditions as per your need

Comment: these codes didnt work for my actual data.

Comment: the thing is i need to compare the first row of the sensor to next 20 and if the difference is less than 10 i need to take that whole 20 rows to another column(filtered) . Then take the 2nd row of the sensor and do the same , if the second row also statisfy the condition then move it to the filter column , the issue is that values shouldnt repeat

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample data.  Generated.   Clearly filter on time could be two date times,  I've just picked certain hours.  For stable, example selected values that are between 45th & 55th percentile.

```
import numpy as np
t = pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,1,10), dt.date(2021,1,11), freq="min")
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":t, "val":np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(len(t)),size=1)[0]})
# filter on hour and val.  val between 45th and 55th percentile
df2 = df[df.time.dt.hour.between(3,4) & df.val.between(df.val.quantile(.45), df.val.quantile(.55))]
```

### output

```
               time      val
2021-01-10 03:13:00 0.000499
2021-01-10 03:41:00 0.000512
2021-01-10 04:00:00 0.000541
2021-01-10 04:39:00 0.000413
```

### rolling window

Question was updated to state **stable** is defined as next `window` rows with a +/- `rng` output in a new column.

Using this definition, using `rolling()` capability with a `lambda` function to check that all subsequent rows within window are within tolerance levels of the first observation in the window.  Any observation out of this range will return *NaN*. Also note last rows will return *NaN* as there are insufficient remaining rows to do test.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""sensor
121
115
122
123
116
117
113
116
113
114
115
112
116
129
123
125
130
120
121
122"""))
df["time"] = pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,1,10), freq="s", periods=len(df))

# how many rows to compare
window = 5
# */- range
rng = 10
if StrictVersion(pd.__version__) < StrictVersion("1.0.0"):
    df["stable"] = df["sensor"].rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.where(pd.Series(x).between(x[0]-rng,x[0]+rng).all(), x[0], np.nan)).shift(-(window-1))
else:
    df["stable"] = df.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.where(x.between(x.values[0]-rng,x.values[0]+rng).all(), x.values[0], np.nan)).shift(-(window-1))
```

### output

```
 sensor                time  stable
    121 2021-01-10 00:00:00   121.0
    115 2021-01-10 00:00:01   115.0
    122 2021-01-10 00:00:02   122.0
    123 2021-01-10 00:00:03   123.0
    116 2021-01-10 00:00:04   116.0
    117 2021-01-10 00:00:05   117.0
    113 2021-01-10 00:00:06   113.0
    116 2021-01-10 00:00:07   116.0
    113 2021-01-10 00:00:08   113.0
    114 2021-01-10 00:00:09     NaN
    115 2021-01-10 00:00:10     NaN
    112 2021-01-10 00:00:11     NaN
    116 2021-01-10 00:00:12     NaN
    129 2021-01-10 00:00:13   129.0
    123 2021-01-10 00:00:14   123.0
    125 2021-01-10 00:00:15   125.0
    130 2021-01-10 00:00:16     NaN
    120 2021-01-10 00:00:17     NaN
    121 2021-01-10 00:00:18     NaN
    122 2021-01-10 00:00:19     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, actually i need some thing like,, take first row and compare(take difference) with the next 20 rows and if the comparison is in between +or- 10 for all the 20 rows then take these values to new column, then take second row and continue the process

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'between'   im getting this error

Comment: 1. I'm using numpy 1.19.5 `np.__version__`. 2. have you ensured that **sensor** column is a number?

Comment: also I'm using pandas 1.2.0.  safer version `df["stable"] = df["sensor"].rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.where(x.between(x.values[0]-rng,x.values[0]+rng).all(), x.values[0], np.nan)).shift(-(window-1))`.just use source column being analysed

Comment: im using 1.16.5. yes sensor column is a number

Comment: I've experimented a bit `between()` is a pandas series method,  not a numpy array method.  Hence for you x is a numpy array,  for me a pandas series.  Your version of numpy is old,  what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: im using 0.25.1 version.  since im using my office lap and this the versions which are installed in it

Comment: what i should do

Comment: interesting :-) I downgraded my pandas version and tried it.  behaviour of `rolling()` has changed.  I've changed answer to switch how it's done based on version of pandas

Comment: yea thhis worked now, so this will work on a large dataset also right! can you explain code please, since all these are new to me

Comment: `x.between(x.values[0]-rng,x.values[0]+rng).all()` is the core, returns `True` if all values are +/- 10 of first row (0th index).  `rolling()` gives subsets to run the test against. `shift()` because rolling will put result against row starting `window`.  On a 90,000 row dataframe, average of 37s within a jupyter notebook

Comment: thank you , what if i need to get the whole value of the window to a new column, that is i need to take the whole value which statisfy the condition and values shouldnt repeat

Comment: my aim is to filter the areas where the sensor data is kind of stable(steady state in a graph)

Comment: What do you mean by whole value of the window? A list, mean, median?

Comment: if we take next 5 rows from first value of the sensor, if it statisfy the condition I need to filter these 5 rows to new column, and then doing the same this time take the 2nd value of the sensor and next 5 rows from it, and so on

Comment: can i ask another question, somehow i did this part. and I'm in one more issue, I cant ask any question in this forum for today, they blocked me for today:p